# Get the size of a Docker image before a pull?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

How does one get the size of a Docker image **before** they pull it to their machine?

Comment: duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134186/docker-how-to-get-image-size?

Comment: As of Dec 2017, docker still doesn't provide any API (any that i know). However, you can try manually searching for image on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com) and then navigating to the 'tag' tab for that image. It will show you the total size of image (still won't show layer info). E.g. info for [Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/ubuntu/tags/)

Answer (score 61):

When you search for a docker image on Docker hub, there will be 2 tabs- `Repo Info` and `Tags`. Open Tags tab and you will see the sizes of all the types of images you can pull for that image.

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question.
  1. Images may be hosted in many other places different than Docker Hub.
  2. The size presented there is compressed one.
  3. This is not an universal API-based approach.

Comment: what is the uncompressed image size? only the compressed image size is available.

Answer (score 25):

1. For image on Docker Hub:

```sh
curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT " "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/<image-name>/tags/?page_size=100" | jq -r '.results[] | select(.name == "<tag-name>") | .images[0].size' | numfmt --to=iec-i
```

2. For images on other registry like Microsoft Container Registry

   - Push the image to Docker Hub and you can get the compressed size of the image on Docker Hub website.
   - Use `docker save` to save image to a .tar file and then compress it a .tar.gz file.

```sh
docker save my-image:latest > my-image.tar

# Compress the .tar file
gzip my-image.tar

# Check the size of the compressed image
ls -lh my-image.tar.gz
```

3. To manually view the manifest data

Use `docker manifest inspect` to observe the manifest data, which shows you the **compressed** size of the image.

- You need to first enable it by editing `~/.docker/config.json` file and set `experimental` to `enable`. Example: `{ "experimental": "enabled" }`. More info at [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest_inspect/).
- Issue `docker manifest inspect -v <registry-domain>/<image-name>` and see add the `size` for the layers but only for your specific architecture (e.g. `amd64`).

```sh
docker manifest inspect -v <registry-domain>/<image-name> | grep size | awk -F ':' '{sum+=$NF} END {print sum}' | numfmt --to=iec-i
```

Noted:

1. It's the compressed size of the layers, not their on-disk size on your server.
2. If the image is a multi-arch image (e.g. `alpine` linux contains `arm`, `amd64` and several architectures), then you'll get the total of those while in actual usage `docker` only uses the relevant `arch`.

Comment: docker inspect worked, except for the number formatting. I got `numfmt: invalid suffix in input: ‘4.37477e+09’` 

Piped output to printf to get around numfmt error. Also you could add `--insecure` if checking an insecure registry.
`docker manifest inspect -v [--insecure] <registry-domain>/<image_name> | grep size | awk -F ':' '{sum+=$NF} END {print sum}' | xargs printf "%f\n" | numfmt --to=iec-i`

Comment: You can also pipe directly to .tar.gz:

`docker save my-image:latest | gzip > test.tar.gz` and check size with `du -h test.tar.gz`

Answer (score 16):

### Docker Hub

Get the compressed size in bytes of an image specific tag.

```sh
# for an official image the namespace is called library
curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/alpine/tags | \
    jq '.results[] | select(.name=="latest") | .full_size'

# 2796860

# here the project namespace is used
curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/jupyter/base-notebook/tags | \
    jq '.results[] | select(.name=="latest") | .full_size'

# 187647701
```

Get the compressed size in bytes of an image tag for a specific architecture / os.

```sh
# selecting an architecture
curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/alpine/tags | \
    jq '.results[] | select(.name=="latest") | .images[] | select (.architecture=="amd64") | .size'

# 2796860

# selecting an architecture and a specific os
curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/hello-world/tags | \                                                                                         
    jq '.results[] | select(.name=="latest") | .images[] | select (.architecture=="amd64" and .os=="linux") | .size'

# 2529
```

### Alternative

An alternative is to use the experimental [`docker manifest inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest_inspect/) command. The advantage is that it does not rely on Docker Hub, **it works as well with other registries** because it's based on the [Image Manifest specification](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/).

```sh
# activate experimental mode
export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled 

docker manifest inspect -v alpine:latest | \
    jq '.[] | select(.Descriptor.platform.architecture=="amd64") | .SchemaV2Manifest.layers[].size'

# 2796860

# need to sum if multiple layers
docker manifest inspect jupyter/base-notebook:latest | \
    jq '[.layers[].size] | add'

# 187647701
```

Answer (score 15):

Getting compressed image size before pull for any registry that serves [Image Manifest V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/):

- Uses [`docker manifest inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest_inspect/) (available by default in recent Docker versions)
- Parses and sums layer sizes from the manifest using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)
- Formats sizes to `iec` standard using [`numfmt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html) (not `si`, sizes in manifests [are](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/#image-manifest-field-descriptions) 1024-based)
- Supports multi-arch manifests

```bash
$ dockersize() { docker manifest inspect -v "$1" | jq -c 'if type == "array" then .[] else . end' |  jq -r '[ ( .Descriptor.platform | [ .os, .architecture, .variant, ."os.version" ] | del(..|nulls) | join("/") ), ( [ .SchemaV2Manifest.layers[].size ] | add ) ] | join(" ")' | numfmt --to iec --format '%.2f' --field 2 | sort | column -t ; }

$ dockersize mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:dotnetapp-buster-slim
linux/amd64  72.96M

$ dockersize ghcr.io/ddelange/pycuda/runtime:3.9-master
linux/amd64  1.84G
linux/arm64  1.80G

$ dockersize python
linux/amd64                    334.98M
linux/arm/v5                   308.21M
linux/arm/v7                   295.69M
linux/arm64/v8                 326.32M
linux/386                      339.74M
linux/mips64le                 314.88M
linux/ppc64le                  343.86M
linux/s390x                    309.52M
windows/amd64/10.0.20348.825   2.20G
windows/amd64/10.0.17763.3165  2.54G
```

- For Debian users: `apt-get install jq`
- For Mac users: `brew install coreutils jq` (coreutils ships `numfmt`)

Comment: Thanks! Works great for many images, but fails for some, e.g.: `dockersize rhub/r-minimal:latest` fails with `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over null (null)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply get all information about the image by the docker hub http  api like that :

```
https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/<image_name>/tags/
```

for example this url `https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/couchdb/tags/latest` return all information about the latest `couchdb` image

```
{
  "creator": 2215,
  "id": 2110662,
  "images": [
    {
      "architecture": "amd64",
      "features": "",
      "variant": null,
      "digest": "sha256:12c59b7f8b202476487c670ba7a042b3a654cd91302335df1bfdff0197f92968",
      "os": "linux",
      "os_features": "",
      "os_version": null,
      "size": 87486230,
      "status": "active",
      "last_pulled": "2022-07-25T17:18:08.778757Z",
      "last_pushed": "2022-07-12T15:29:34.553194Z"
    },
    {
      "architecture": "arm64",
      "features": "",
      "variant": "v8",
      "digest": "sha256:5985d1edef0613a93f2d7349a7cac2296ec956674df1f96d70d4eb23e83e6f80",
      "os": "linux",
      "os_features": "",
      "os_version": null,
      "size": 85620381,
      "status": "active",
      "last_pulled": "2022-07-25T15:30:42.25162Z",
      "last_pushed": "2022-07-12T03:05:55.128925Z"
    },
    {
      "architecture": "ppc64le",
      "features": "",
      "variant": null,
      "digest": "sha256:f667d0d4bf4acaeade0cf8510a4a1384ccd66c08e4ab0b678afb7f8651b9df41",
      "os": "linux",
      "os_features": "",
      "os_version": null,
      "size": 93209105,
      "status": "active",
      "last_pulled": "2022-07-25T12:28:16.460623Z",
      "last_pushed": "2022-07-12T05:26:46.295412Z"
    }
  ],
  "last_updated": "2022-07-12T15:30:03.436304Z",
  "last_updater": 1156886,
  "last_updater_username": "doijanky",
  "name": "latest",
  "repository": 545837,
  "full_size": 87486230,
  "v2": true,
  "tag_status": "active",
  "tag_last_pulled": "2022-07-25T17:18:08.778757Z",
  "tag_last_pushed": "2022-07-12T15:30:03.436304Z"
}
```

the image size (in byet) is : `87486230`

if you need only the full size you can get it fetch the json and extract the property full_size by any json processor like `jq` or other

for example :

```
curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/couchdb/tags/latest | jq 'select(.name=="latest") | .full_size'
//87486230
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really look into the docker code for pull operation, I think your answer is there. If the image of the container is not cached, then during pulling of the image, docker first collects the information about the image from the registry like number of layers, size of each layers etc. etc.

I would refer to read this file.

https://github.com/moxiegirl/docker/blob/master/distribution/xfer/download.go